# Scraping website | How do I create a JSON file?

Tags: jquery

**I am just starting to learn scraping websites.**

The website I'm scraping has a main class "Content". Inside the Content div are the articles and the heading of the article is inside the `<h2>` tags.

I have figured out somehow to refer to the headers with the following code. Now I want to save all the headers in a JSON file. How do I create objects for each headings. Clearly my code below just replaces the *title* of the *obj* with every iteration.

```
var title, date, img_url, permalink;
var obj = { title : "", date : "", img_url : "", permalink : ""};

        // ======== Extracting Title ================
        $('#Content').filter(function(){
            var data = $(this);
            let headers = data.find('h2');

            headers.each(function (i, el) {
                obj.title = $(el).text();
            })
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want an array of objects similar to `{title: "Some title"}` for each `<h2>` element, then you can simply use

```js
const headerObjects = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#Content h2')).map(h2 => ({
  title: h2.textContent
}))

console.info(headerObjects)
```

```html
<div id="Content">
<h2>Title 1</h2>
<p>Here's some text</p>
<h2>Title 2</h2>
<p>Some more text</p>
<h2>Last title</h2>
<p>One more paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Reference:

- [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
- [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code,.In this code when you click the「Create file」button it will create download link.That link lead to download json file formated o/p.

```js
var json = [];
$("h2").each(function(i) {
  var title = $(this).html();
  item = {};
  item ["title"] = title;
  json.push(item);
});

(function () {
  var textFile = null,
      makeTextFile = function (text) {
        var data = new Blob([text], {type: 'application/json'});
        if (textFile !== null) {
          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
        }
        textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
        return textFile;
      };
  create.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
    link.href = makeTextFile(JSON.stringify(json, null, 4));
    link.style.display = 'block';
  }, false);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Content">
  <h2>Title 1</h2>
  <p>Here's some text</p>
  <h2>Title 2</h2>
  <p>Some more text</p>
  <h2>Last title</h2>
  <p>One more paragraph</p>
</div>
<button id="create">Create file</button>
<a download="info.txt" id="downloadlink" style="display: none">Download</a>
```

Here is the working jsfiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/o1kvk63o/

I think it should be helps you